# collinearity problem with recursive feature elimination

Tags: feature-selection

I am performing feature selection using RFE on 80 features which includes highly correlated features.

The issue here is when I shuffle the order of columns and apply RFE I get different set of selected features. Can somebody please explain me why is this happening?

Secondly, I also tried feature selection using RFE after removing highly correlated features whose correlation coefficient is greater than 0.7. But still the results are different.

I am applying Lasso and XGB within the RFE to calculate the feature importance.

Can you please suggest me an appropriate way of doing this? Does RFE have any drawbacks that I need to be aware of?

Comment: Because it's all very random and unstable, automatic variable selection procedures will not save you.